# Can you guarantee unique sequential numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint, sequential

So, we're processing credit card payments, and each payment needs a unique reference ID. We are using MySQL.

There is a `payments` table which has an auto incrementing primary key id, processing_date, created_at, updated_at. My issue is that this record cannot be persisted until after the payment has been processed (this process cannot be changed due the applications workflow). Due to this we cannot simply use the primary key as it would not exist until after the payment has been processed and have since added a `reference_id` column with a unique constraint.

My question is, is there a reliable method of generating a sequential (or close to) number based on an existing table column (i.e. using something like `MAX(reference_id) + 1`), processing the payment (using curl) then inserting the payment record into the table with the previously generated `reference_id` whilst ensuring uniqueness. Essentially reserving the previously generated reference_id with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another column to your payments table as a status / confirmed flag. When the payment starts you insert the values and set the status to "started" (or whatever)  this way you can use your auto generated id.

When the payment is completed you can then set the flag to "completed". If a payment is rejected delete the row.

To optimise this you could also create a housekeeping procedure that runs every night and deletes rows with a status of "started" that are over 2 days old or something similar.

Comment: This is similar to the approach we're currently considering.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to base it off an existing column. If you get 2 transactions going at the same time you can end up with 2 transactions with the same ID.

Base it on a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), or a timestamp.

I have a similar system and the transaction ID is MMDDYYHHMMSS + 8 digit random number. This is okay for low volume transactions and it very unlikely there will be 2 or more duplicate transactions in 1 second.

Many gateways use this same scheme.

The UUID is the safest as it guarantees it is globally unique.

Comment: Generating unique numbers isn't the issue, it's ensuring they're sequential. There can be skipped elements in the sequence (with reason). Which rules out probably any use of random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra table for the reference_id and update this value each time you need a new number. Wrap everything in a transaction and you're save. The usage of a MySQL-variable makes things very easy in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE reference_id(
id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO reference_id (id) VALUES (1);

REVOKE INSERT, DELETE, TRUNCATE FROM [all users];
```

-- the real job:

> ```
> BEGIN;
> SET @i = 0;
> SELECT id + 1 INTO @i FROM reference_id FOR UPDATE;
> UPDATE reference_id SET id = @i;
> INSERT INTO other_table(ref_id, content) VALUES(@i, 'bla');
> COMMIT;
> ```

Because of the lock you won't have integrity problems with concurrency, not even after a ROLLBACK. But users might have to wait.